# Applying texture to a wire frame

Tags: c++, opengl

I drew a wireSphere using Opengl.Then I added texture to it. It show in this machine. But I don't show the texture in another machine. It show only the wire sphere without texturing.

Comment: _Show code._ Which machines? You're using GLUT? NPOT textures? The code's texturing a _wireframe_? Is the code checking for errors?

Comment: Yaa. I used GLUT. I draw a wireSphre in manually. Then applied a texture. It works on the machine which I developed in. But it didn't work in another machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the machine it's not working have the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, and check if your texture have a non-power of two width or height. Older hardware do not support textures which dimensions are not power of two.